# Rewriting subquery as JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

UPDATE: Thanks to Sifu Bill's advice I have amended the SQL query. Now it returns the correct number of distinct assets (five).

Is it possible to rewrite the following subquery as a JOIN?

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Asset_ID, work_order_id, status_id,
downtime_hours, date_completed
FROM dbo.mtvw_wo_reason1
WHERE (Asset_ID IN
(SELECT TOP 5 Asset_ID from mtvw_wo_reason1
WHERE (Date_Completed BETWEEN '1-Oct-2009' AND '31-Oct-2009')
GROUP BY Asset_ID
ORDER BY SUM(Downtime_hours) DESC))
```

The output follows:

```
Asset_ID work_order_id status_id downtime_hours Date_Completed

SFM2019 2009-724    Completed   .5000   2009-09-01 17:55:09.000
SFM2019 2009-761    Completed   .5000   2009-09-15 09:03:39.000
SFM2019 2009-828    Completed   8.0000  2009-10-02 00:00:00.000
SFM2043 2009-683    Completed   .5000   2009-08-14 00:00:00.000
SFM2043 2009-734    Completed   1.0000  2009-09-05 00:54:33.000
SFM2043 2009-741    Completed   1.0000  2009-09-08 17:05:09.000
SFM2043 2009-756    Completed   .5000   2009-09-14 07:56:41.000
SFM2043 2009-792    Completed   1.0000  2009-09-22 00:00:00.000
SFM2043 2009-826    Completed   8.0000  2009-10-03 02:00:19.130
SFM2043 2009-983    Completed   1.0000  2009-10-30 00:00:00.000
SFM2045 2009-794    Completed   17.0000 2009-09-24 00:00:00.000
SFM2045 2009-808    Completed   1.0000  2009-09-26 16:01:25.850
SFM2045 2009-811    Completed   3.0000  2009-09-27 09:47:45.543
SFM2045 2009-816    Completed   24.0000 2009-09-30 15:14:35.000
SFM2045 2009-858    Completed   3.0000  2009-10-12 00:00:00.000
SFM2045 2009-861    Completed   .5000   2009-10-13 01:11:50.900
SFM2045 2009-975    Completed   1.0000  2009-10-28 00:00:00.000
SFM2045 2009-984    Completed   3.0000  2009-10-30 00:00:00.000
SFM2088 2009-777    Completed   .5000   2009-10-01 12:49:57.000
SFM2088 2009-853    Completed   .5000   2009-10-09 00:00:00.000
SFM2088 2009-855    Completed   10.0000 2009-10-09 00:00:00.000
SFM2200 2009-753    Completed   8.0000  2009-09-11 00:00:00.000
SFM2200 2009-830    Completed   8.0000  2009-10-09 00:00:00.000
```

In essence the query needs to:

> Return the top 5 assets with the
>   highest cumulative downtime for the
>   month of October, and a breakdown of
>   the associated workorders for these
>   assets

The query has to be rewritten in such a way that does not require the the existence of Date_Completed criteria in the inner query (is this even possible?). Using Sifu Bill's answer yielded only 11 rows (there should be 23):

Output from Sifu Bill's query:

```
Asset_ID work_order_id status_id downtime_hours Date_Completed

SFM2045 2009-858    Completed   3.0000  2009-10-12 00:00:00.000
SFM2045 2009-861    Completed   .5000   2009-10-13 01:11:50.900
SFM2045 2009-975    Completed   1.0000  2009-10-28 00:00:00.000
SFM2045 2009-984    Completed   3.0000  2009-10-30 00:00:00.000
SFM2200 2009-830    Completed   8.0000  2009-10-09 00:00:00.000
SFM2043 2009-826    Completed   8.0000  2009-10-03 02:00:19.130
SFM2043 2009-983    Completed   1.0000  2009-10-30 00:00:00.000
SFM2088 2009-777    Completed   .5000   2009-10-01 12:49:57.000
SFM2088 2009-853    Completed   .5000   2009-10-09 00:00:00.000
SFM2088 2009-855    Completed   10.0000 2009-10-09 00:00:00.000
SFM2019 2009-828    Completed   8.0000  2009-10-02 00:00:00.000
```

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: That's a subquery, but not a correlated subquery.

Comment: Sifu Bill, according to Wikipedia a correlated subquery is:

1. One that uses values from the outer query in its WHERE clause.
2. The sub-query is evaluated once for each row processed by the outer query.

That is what I wish to accomplish, could you provide some insight into this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT 
        Asset_ID, 
        work_order_id, 
        status_id, 
        downtime_hours 
FROM    dbo.mtvw_wo_reason1 INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  TOP 5 
                    Asset_ID 
            from    mtvw_wo_reason1 
            GROUP   BY Asset_ID, Date_Completed 
            HAVING  Date_Completed BETWEEN '1-Oct-2009' and '31-Oct-2009' 
            ORDER BY    SUM(Downtime_hours) DESC
        ) sub ON dbo.mtvw_wo_reason1.Asset_ID = sub.Asset_ID
```

EDIT for comment:

```
SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT         
        Asset_ID,         
        work_order_id,         
        status_id,         
        downtime_hours ,
        sub.Date_Completed --added
FROM    dbo.mtvw_wo_reason1 INNER JOIN        
        (                
            SELECT  TOP 5                                 
                    Asset_ID,
                    Date_Completed --added
            from    mtvw_wo_reason1                 
            GROUP   BY Asset_ID, Date_Completed                 
            HAVING  Date_Completed BETWEEN '1-Oct-2009' and '31-Oct-2009'                 
            ORDER BY SUM(Downtime_hours) DESC        
        ) sub ON dbo.mtvw_wo_reason1.Asset_ID = sub.Asset_ID
```

Comment: That worked a treat! It needed a slight modification to specify the table name though. Thanks!

Comment: Sifu astander, is it possible for the Date_Completed column from the subquery to be selected on the main (outside) query? Thank you for the enlightenment.

Comment: Sifu astander, sorry for my incompetence as the problem was not explained clearly.

I wish to remove the "HAVING" clause within the subquery. The reason for it is because I'm stuck using a crippled reporting tool that requires column names to be exposed in the main SELECT command.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess what you *intend* this query to do.  I suggest that when you ask how to fix a query that isn't doing what you want, you include in your question a clear statement about what the purpose of the query is.  Otherwise people who answer can't infer from a wrong query what would be the right one.

Also it's helpful if you include the definition of the table.  The best way to show this is the Data Definition Language (i.e. `CREATE TABLE`) that you used to define the table.

I'm assuming this statement describes your desired query result:

> "All rows during October for each Asset_ID's that have the most cumulative downtime during that month."

You can get the assets that have the most downtime during October like you were doing in the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Asset_ID 
FROM mtvw_wo_reason1
WHERE Date_Completed BETWEEN '2009-10-1' and '2009-10-31'
GROUP  BY Asset_ID
ORDER BY SUM(Downtime_hours) DESC
```

Notice that this query could be run standalone.  This is a clue that if you use it as a subquery, it's *non-correlated*.  That is, it contains no reference to values in an outer query.

You don't want to add `Date_Completed` to the `GROUP BY` clause as @astander showed.  You want groups to be per asset alone, so you can get accurate `SUM()` per asset.

However, the select-list of this table doesn't include the other columns from the table, and the rows are reduced to a single row per `Asset_ID` by the `GROUP BY`.  So it doesn't give all the information you need.  Therefore you need to run it as a subquery.

```
SELECT m.Asset_ID, m.work_order_id, m.status_id, m.downtime_hours, m.Date_Completed
FROM dbo.mtvw_wo_reason1 m
JOIN (SELECT TOP 5 Asset_ID 
    FROM mtvw_wo_reason1
    WHERE Date_Completed BETWEEN '2009-10-1' and '2009-10-31'
    GROUP  BY Asset_ID
    ORDER BY SUM(Downtime_hours) DESC) sub
  ON (m.Asset_ID = sub.Asset_ID)
WHERE m.Date_Completed BETWEEN '2009-10-1' and '2009-10-31';
```

You *do* need to restrict by `Date_Completed` in both the subquery and the outer query.

PS: From what I've read, the only valid use of `TOP 100 PERCENT` is when you're defining a `VIEW` with an `ORDER BY` clause at the end.

Comment: Sifu Bill, thank you for taking time to reply. I learned a lot from it.

The SQL query needs to return the top 5 assets with the highest cumulative downtime for the month of October, and a breakdown of the associated workorders for these assets. I will edit the original question to provide more detail. Thank  you for your patience.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail in your question.  I can't think of a straightforward way to solve this query without the condition in the subquery for Date_Completed.

Comment: The output you showed includes rows outside of October for the assets.  I had assumed this would not be desired -- do you want all rows for these assets to the beginning of time?  Anyway, if you remove the `WHERE` clause on the *outer* query, you should get all the rows for these assets.

Comment: Sifu Bill, thank you for pointing out the mistake. The SQL query itself is correct; the view was selecting the column from the wrong table. There are too many columns with the same name in different tables. Sadly I do not have the authority to modify the database schema. :(